# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CustomHeaderComponent')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just created a new component on my own project, but I always get the same error message. I'm sure the injection code is correct and the module and component export logic are also correct. I can't understand what is wrong.

**custom-header.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-header',
  templateUrl: './custom-header.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CustomHeaderComponent {

  @Input() parentPageTitle: string;
  @Input() pageTitle: string;
  @Input() createButtonName: string;
  @Input() createButtonFunction: () => void;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) {
  }
}
```

**custom-header.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomHeaderComponent} from 'app/modules';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomHeaderComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    CustomHeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    CommonModule,
  ]
})
export class CustomHeaderModule {
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './header/custom-header.module';
export * from './header/custom-header.component';
```

**Error Message**

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CustomHeaderComponent')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CustomHeaderComponent')
    at Module.CustomHeaderComponent (custom-header.module.ts:11:26)
    at custom-header.module.ts:8:5
    at Module.11151 (custom-header.module.ts:11:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.33630 (index.ts:8:60)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.3265 (ganymede-users.module.ts:22:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.50252 (custom-header.module.ts:11:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:1)
    at zone.js:1279:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25505:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:1)
```

Comment: I guess it's some kind of initialization problem (reading CustomHeaderComponent before it being parsed) - maybe an import loop somewhere (higher) in the code. Changing order of exported items in `index.ts` files could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnChanges because  is a lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes:

```
 import {Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';



export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
 
  @Input() message = '';    
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  
     if (this.message){
      //do something here....
      
     }
     
  }
  
}
```